# Netsuite suitescript 2.0 load Record not Source, When Save Record get Error: Record has been changed

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm user suitescript 2.0. In the custom Record Types, I build client-script to load 1 records from ITEM_FULFILLMENT.

```
var ffid = 123
var itemffo = record.load({
                type : record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,   
                id: ffid,
                isDynamic : false/true
            });
```

After that, I clicked on button Save.
I get error: "Record has been changed"

I did not change any itemffo. Just get data in it. Please, help me to fix this problem?!

Comment: I would check the system notes to see who changed the record. Could it be that somebody else changed it or is your user shown as the one making the changes?

Comment: oh, no. At the time I coded, Only me run it on Developer enviroment, record save normal if I don't use record.load.

Comment: I read help: When a SuiteScript 2.0 script creates, copies, loads, or transforms a record in standard mode, the record’s body fields and sublist line items are not sourced, calculated, and validated until the record is saved (submitted) with Record.save(options).  >>> STILL error

Comment: The error is thrown on your custom record, not the Fulfillment record. Can it be the you have some user event on the fulfillment records that manipulates your record on load?

Comment: on beforeLoad? I have some code on user event script in FF. But I thought it's only effect in FF record?! How can I fix if I met the problem you told Igor?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is a difference between `context.oldrecord` and `context.newrecord` .
Any other script such as ClientScript/UserEvent Script/WorkflowAction Script can change/modify the value in  `context.newrecord` .

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you have error in your code. Try to write the code inside a try catch.

Comment: Dear @E56,  I wrote .load just for load data from ITEM_FULFILLMENT to get information in it. I got correct data. I did all with information i need. But no get error. after that, I try only this code. if get error when I click "saved".

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it not  work. Still get "Record has been changed"